# Table with auto-generating data in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have four columns, employee, role, discipline and available from created in A1,B1,C1, and D1. I selected the four cells and the four beneath in A2, B2, C2 and D2 and turned it in to a table. I then pasted the following formula which is used to pull data together from two other tables in to A2 but unfortunately I get a spill error -

`=FILTER(VSTACK(FILTER(M3:Q50000,M3:M50000<>""),FILTER(S3:W50000,S3:S50000<>"")),{1,1,1,0,1})`

Is it possible to construct a table in this way?

Comment: no - you can't use spill formulas in a table

Comment: Thanks Ike, I'll find a different approach.

Comment: @ike since your comment is the correct answer to this Q, it would be better to add it as an answer

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to keep using Excel table, and you want to populate specific column that uses an array formula, such as `UNIQUE` or any other spill formula, you can create a *Hidden* tab (hide it if you want) where you use `UNIQUE` for example, then to refer in your Excel Table to your calculated array. Let's say the first element is: `HIdden!A1`, then you populate your table expanding down the formula.